# Attiny85 PB4 works for analog output but not PB3?

Tags: attiny85

I can get PB4 to work but not PB3 on my ATtinny85.  I'm just lighting up an led (with 150 ohm resistor) (using internal 16mhz)

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);

}
void loop() {
  analogWrite(3, 15);//does not work
  analogWrite(4, 15);//works
  delay(500); 
  analogWrite(3, 0);//does not work
  analogWrite(4, 0);//works
  delay(500);
}
```

[image]

Comment: According to the diagram, only PB0 and PB1 support PWM (purple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardware `PWM` is only suported on pins with output compare altenate function on it. The pinout in your question shows `Attiny13` but the rest of your question is about `Attiny85`, which has different capabilities from `Attiny13`

[image: Attiny85 pinout]

As you can see, only pins with `PWM` capability are `PB0`, `PB1` and `PB4`

Comment: ohhh, thank you, i didn't even realize i was looking at the 13a pinout by mistake